# Corona SDK dev app black sreens on android tablet

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, tablet

Hi I am developing an app with corona sdk. It works on iPhone, iPad and my android phone (2.2). However, on samsung galaxy tab 2 the app loads the initial menu then blacks out. I'm still using the free version of corona. Also I can't change the target build OS for android. 
Here's my build settings. Thanks for helping out. I am stumped.

```
settings = {

    orientation = {
        default = "portrait",
        supported = { "portrait"}
    },

    iphone = {
        plist = {
                        "Icon.png", 
                        "Icon@2x.png", 
                        "Icon-72.png",
            UIStatusBarHidden = false,
            UIPrerenderedIcon = true, -- set to false for "shine" overlay
            --UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = true, -- uncomment to quit app on suspend

        }
    },

    android =                                                               
    {
        versionCode = "2"                                                   
    },
    androidPermissions = 
    {
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
    },        

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use some debug tools? So you can see if there is an error

Comment: @FLCLester Did you ever resolve this?